# Unable to suppress SQL Server Error Message Popup in C# Application for SQL error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

We have a C# application that is to run automatically using Windows Task Manager.

The problem is when there's a SQL error, a message comes up as shown in the attached image.

The error message is a dialog and it's waiting for the user to click "OK".

When we run this manually it's fine since the end user can simply click "OK" and the C# app then goes to the exception part of the code.

However, that doesn't work for us in an automated environment where the process gets stuck and just hangs since this is automated and nobody is there to attend to this dialog box.

We already have error handling and a log is created and an email is sent out.  But we simply can't get to that section of the code since the error message dialog box has popped up waiting for user input which can't happen in an automated environment.

How can we turn off or suppress this is error message dialog box without actually suppressing the error?

I tried several things, but they only suppressed the entire error as if it did not happen.  We don't want that.  We simply don't want the error message dialog box to appear.

[image: SQL Server Error message popup in VS]

Comment: Without seeing your error handling code, no one can help you. Since the same thing happens when run the app manually, then your error handling obviously doesn't have the ability to suppress the error / dialog that is currently part of this logic. In other words, your app doesn't "handle" the error - it simply presents the error information in a dialog. You will need to change that. How? Depends on how you want your app-as-service to react to this (or any other) error.

Comment: According your error in the screen, I think it is very possible for you to use try catch sentence and use the Messegbox.show(ex.tostring). If so, please change the messagebox code to the code that handles the log error.

Answer (score 0):

Data conversation failed. Column value X cannot convert to int. Open Stored procedure write try_cast/try_convert insted of  cast/convert.

Comment: That error was put on purpose.  My goal was to force the stored procedure to generate an error.  When it does this, a Error Message popup comes up and it is waiting for a user to click "OK".   That is the crux of the problem.  I want to avoid that popup from happening.   What can I do to avoid the popup?